# what to use columns or thumb nails for recent posts (bootstrap, HTML/CSS, JAVA)

Tags: html, css

i am a starter, so pls bear, if the questions is altogether dud,

iam using bootstrap3 to create a frontpage of my website (not for customer).

the front page will look like pin interest, or blog, rows of posts (photo,text,details)

the page would be a 4rows x 3 columns page.

my question is.
if the whole intention, is, these 4 rows, must always, show new posts (this is no wp site, but complete web application) i.e, say ex: new job.

these 4rows x 3 col,  must be columns or thumnails.

means.
when i create a 8 x 4 container on the front page 
there are few options for me, in the container 8, i can either put  3 columns or 3 thumbnails.

so which one i must use. or both are same. i am asking thing question, bcz, the site is not static and the 4x3 will always display... the latest post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it's completely the same. Just choose the solution that better suits dynamic manipulation. I could be of more help with some examples of what you want to accomplish exactly. Some code would be nice too.

Comment: thanks alkis, target something like this http://www.kickstarter.com/discover?ref=nav                                 a front page with posts organized in a row column view, for that, i had two options with bootstrap 3, one is with columns other one is with thumnails... code as below (are both same)

Comment: tryed to both the code, but bots are not allowing me to post, as i am a new user : - (